# how to Link/Merge/Combine two contacts in android?

Tags: android, contacts

**How can i **link two contacts** for example an *email address* and *a phone number* from my application?
thanks,**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the answer is ContactsContract.AggregationExceptions

for more information, go to Click http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.AggregationExceptions.html?